# Phonegap on Android XmlHttpRequest Works in Emulator, Not on Device

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, cordova, xmlhttprequest

I saw a very similiar question that didn't ever get fully answered. It's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523720/phonegap-android-project-works-on-emulator-not-on-actual-phone).

The basic problem is that I finally got an XmlHttpRequest AJAX call working with Phonegap on Android, but the catch is that it only works on the Android emulator.

When I run it on the emulator, I get an alert with the XML reply. When I run it on the device, I get an alert with nothing, it's just blank.

I'm running the latest Phonegap, 1.9, and the emulator runs Android 2.3.3, API level 10. The device is a Samsung Galaxy S running 2.3.5.

Here's the JavaScript being used to make the request:

```
function sendXMLRequest() {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST","http://www.xxx.com/path/to.cgi",true);

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0) {
                    alert("Server responded with: " + request.responseText);
                }
            }
        }

    postdata = "big long XML string that I've quadruple checked";
    try {
        request.send(postdata);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        alert("Error, could not locate vehicle, please try again later.");
    }
}
```

I have cordova.xml and plugins.xml and I have all of the permissions, and I've tried removing the INTERNET permission in the manifest. The device definitely has an internet connection.

Thanks in advance for the help, I appreciate it.

Comment: i've run into the same problem... request response is blank on android 2.x device but works on the emulator. The apparent fix by including status == 0 did not work for me either.

Comment: I hate to be like this, but I honestly have no idea what fixed it for us. Sometime through development, after we left this alone for a while, it magically worked again. Most of the time. I can only suggest making sure you have the most recent version of Phonegap, and trying to run it over WiFi, as well as the cell networks.